# Hard to understand return_value for Python Mock Class in the following example

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I had a hard time understanding the choice of using `return_value`. See the following example

```
# my_module.py

def query(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = 1")
    return cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

```
# test_query.py

import pytest
from unittest.mock import Mock

# Import the module containing the function to test
import my_module

def test_query():
    # Set up the mock database connection
    connection = Mock()
    cursor = connection.cursor.return_value
    cursor.fetchone.return_value = ("Alice",)

    # Call the function under test
    result = my_module.query(connection)

    # Assert that the function has the expected behavior
    assert result == "Alice"
```

My question is in `test_query.py`, why do I need the first `return_value`? It looks like if `cursor = connection.cursor.return_value`, I can replace the `cursor` in `cursor.fetchone.return_value = ("Alice",)`, which then becomes `connection.cursor.return_value.fetchone.return_value = ("Alice",)`? Why does this code require two `return_value` ?

Without the first `return_value`, I received `TypeError: 'Mock' object is not subscriptable` after running pytest

The broader question is when should I use `return_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First lets make sure we understand what **Mock** is. You can think of it as an object that's every attribute or function call returns another object of type **Mock**.

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

m = Mock()
for cls in [m, m.any_attribute, m.any_function("any_param"), m.any_function.return_value]:
    assert isinstance(cls, Mock)
```

We can easilly implement such behaviour by ourself:

```
class MyMock:
    def __getattribute__(self, _: str):
        return MyMock()

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return MyMock()
```

However `return_value` has a special meaning. With `return value` you ask for (or set by yourself) result of calling specified function.

Now, what our goal is? Our goal is to make `cursor.fetchone()` function return something that is subscriptable (because we ask for first element with `[0]`). But with such syntax:

```
connection.cursor.fetchone.return_value = ("Alice, )
```

We are mocking result of calling `fetchone` from `connection.cursor`, not `connection.cursor()`. It would work fine only if `cursor` is a `property`.

To sum up, whenever you see a function call you use `return_value` and in case of attributes you don't.